# Insert query format comprising of date

Tags: java, mysql

i'm having a table order comprising of feilds `oid` `odate` `ddate` `ShippingAddr` `Email`

,where `oid` is auto-incremented and I'm using the following query-

```
"INSERT INTO order (Odate,Ddate, ShippingAddr, Email) 
 VALUES ('" + o.getOdate() + "','" + o.getDdate() + "','" + o.getShippingAddr() + "','" + Email + "')";
```

but it gives a `Mysqlexception` please help

Comment: How are you performing this query?  Show us the part where this string is being actively used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your query is vulnerable for SQL injection. So I suggest you to use prepared statements.

`order` is a reserved word for SQL. For MySQL You should quote the reserved word if you want to use them as table or field names

```
Connection c= null;
PreparedStatement ps= null;

c = setTheDBConnection(); //just for example

ps = c.preparedStatement("INSERT INTO `order` (Odate,Ddate,ShippingAddr,Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

ps.setString(1, o.getOdate());
ps.setString(2, o.getDdate());
ps.setString(3, o.getShippingAddr());
ps.setString(4, Email);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: No *don't* do it like this. This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just pointed why the error occurs. I do not care SQL injection at the moment. It is OP's matter.

Comment: Regardless of the context - SQL injection vulnerabilities are bad.  Claiming that they're not your responsibility is, well...irresponsible.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ: Whereas I think it's important to point this out *anywhere* it occurs.

Comment: OP has not mentioned anything about whether he is using statement or preparedstatement.This answer is exactly according to the question

Comment: @JonSkeet is it OK now?

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ: Well, you've fixed it but not given any indication of *why* it should be done this way. I'm also alarmed by a date value being specified as a string (I'll edit something about that into my answer). I've removed the downvote, but not upvoted as I still think it could be significantly more helpful.

Comment: @javaBeginner: Whether he's using Statement or PreparedStatement, the original answer was irresponsible (IMO) in not mentioning the *gaping* security (and correctness) hole.

Answer (score 1):

Don't build up your SQL like this at all. Instead use *parameterized* SQL, and set the various parameter values.

```
// You still need to escape the "order" table name as per Özkan's answer
String sql = 
   "INSERT INTO `order` (ODate, DDate, ShippingAddr, Email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql))
{
    pst.setDate(1, o.getOdate());
    pst.setDate(2, o.getDdate());
    pst.setString(3, o.getShippingAddr());
    pst.setString(4, Email);
    pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

This will:

- Avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Make it clearer when the problem is with the SQL and when it's with the data (the problem with the SQL in your question isn't really with dates, but they ended up confusing the issue)
- Separate your code from your data
- Avoid conversion issues with dates etc

Note that I've used `setDate` for the `ODate` and `DDate` values. I would *hope* they are "date" types (or something similar) in your database, and that `o.getODate()` returns a `Date` - or perhaps a Joda Time type such as `LocalDate`. If you're actually just using strings for everything in your data model, that's another thing to fix (urgently, IMO).